# CouchBase 2.5 2 nodes in replica: 1 node fail: the service is no more available

Tags: replication, couchbase, failover

We are testing Couchbase with a two node cluster with one replica.

When we stop the service on one node, the other one does not respond until we restart the service or manually failover the stopped node.

Is there a way to maintain the service from the good node when one node is temporary unavailable?

Comment: * What does your test code look like?

Comment: @Paddy: i didn't write a test code, simply i raise up the 2 nodes, i write some documents in one node and other documents in the second one (via web panel) and after i try to see what happens if i stop the service on one node.

Comment: You have no say where that document lives it does not matter which node's UI you used to input. More than likely all 3 document are on node that is down.
* Try your test with a 1000 documents.
* Or you can use the cbc hash command to see where that document is.

This section in the manual explains it better: http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/#vbuckets

Answer (score 0):

If a node goes down then in order to activate the replicas on the other node you will need to manually fail it over. If you want this to happen automatically then you can enable auto-failover, but in order to use that feature I'm pretty sure you must have at least a three node cluster. When you want to add the failed node back then you can just re-add it to the cluster and rebalance.

Comment: Yes, so works the failover procedure.
But if the server doesn't crash but it's simply not available for a full minute, does that mean that the cluster is not available for that entire minute ?
Should i configure automatic failover within 30 seconds and then re-add the server manually after the failover (and that's not an optimal option)?
Is there a better way for those cases ?

Comment: Only the server that is down will be unavailable. The rest of the nodes in the cluster will continue to serve data. I would also recommend using auto-failover in your production environment since I agree it isn't optimal to have to manually fail over a server. I believe this is the best option.

Comment: It's not true for what I saw: in a configuration of 2 nodes if one is unavailable also the other does not respond: also for its active documents.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case so I would guess there is a client side issue. You might want to open a separate question and post your code.